# HttpClient hangs when doing a second request

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, freeze

I'm writing a java app that can login and shop around on the website. I'm having an issue where my HttpClient is hanging when I try to execute a second HttpResponse/Post. It was working fine before, not sure why it started hanging up. I don't get any errors, it just sits there and gets stuck. The only change I made that may be possibily causing this hang up is that I'm using HttpGet to retrieve tokens so I can login to the website.

Here's how I'm setting up the httpClient

```
private static BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
private static HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

The rest is just a standard httpget & httppost, then httpclient.execute();

The first sequence is my program queries the website and retrieves the token, then I send a POST with the token to sign in. After that my program queries a website again to get product information, then adds to the cart. But it hangs at the second POST.

Could I be missing a flush somewhere? I was reading somewhere that this way of HttpClient closes itself. And the DefaultHttpClient has been deprecated.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"? is there an exception? what's the message?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your "standard" usage of the class ... you're probably not cleaning up something you should be ... you should provide a **short** example that demonstrates the problem. **ETA**: You even ask if you're missing a flush somewhere -- how on earth would we know without code?

Comment: I followed this tutorial, http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Answer (score 49):

In the tutorial posted it below, they did not mention I should use post.releaseConnection(); It caused my code to hangup, so I addeded the releaseConnection() function after every POST/GET. I hope that is the proper way to clean the code up.

Comment: Thankx men, saved a day

Comment: 9 years later, and saved me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

## Option 1: Reset the Request

[`releaseConnection()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html#releaseConnection()) or [`reset()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/AbstractExecutionAwareRequest.html#reset()) will "reset internal state of the request making it reusable":

```java
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/get");
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {   
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)  
    // do something with response
} finally {
    request.releaseConnection()
}
```

## Option 2: Close the Response

Call `response.close()` once we are finished handling the response:

```java
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/get");
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    try {   
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)  
    // do something with response
    } finally {
        response.close()
    }
}
```

We can tidy this up by adding the response to the try-with-resources statement:

```java
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/get");
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
     CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
    // do something with response
}
```